# How to use this.http.post multiple times?

Tags: angular, typescript

Using Angular10 and Typescript.

Actually, I can use this.http.post multiple times since I reload the page after calling it.
My questions is, how could I do that but no using 'window.location.relaod()'.

So, I am opening a Dialog to edit Parent's data. It only works if I use

```
dialog.afterClosed(){
window.location.reload()};
```

Function behind 'send button':

```
async onOkClick() {
var e = await this.groceryListCrudService.post(this.myData);
this.dialogRef.close('Ok');
}
```

This is my post function:

```
post(item: Partial<PortFolio>) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.url, item, this.httpOptions).subscribe({
      next: (data) => {
        this.post = data.id;
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error('There was an error!', error);
      },
    });
  }
```

This is the Error I get when I click on it twice (even I wait it to be inserted on database):

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
> this.groceryListCrudService.post is not a function TypeError:
> this.groceryListCrudService.post is not a function

I don't know what else should be useful to show here. If it is missing something, I can show more of the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you injected `groceryListCrudService` in your constructor?

Comment: This may have something to do with the fact that a subscribe object does not return in the same way that a Promise does.

Comment: @NehalJaisalmeria I think so, It is what I've inside constructor: 'private groceryListCrudService: GroceryListCrudService'.

Comment: @shn Hmmm.. I know I am sending same type of variable values. I am not sure how promise would work in different ways in this case.

Comment: Please create a sample stackblitz on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gfe5uj

Comment: Instead of ```this.post = data.id``` have you tried ```return data.id``` ?

Comment: Thank you @NehalJaisalmeria, I appreciate your help!

Comment: @DaniloKörber you got it!! It solved mt problem! Turn it in an answer and let me give you points! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `this.post = data.id` you have to use `return data.id`. You cannot assign a value to the function itself.